# How to launch a steam game using TideSDK?

Tags: javascript, tidesdk

So I'm  trying to build an app using TideSDK (javascript) and I need it to run a steam game (preferably using the steam link: steam://run/440) and any other game that is not on steam using its actual path, something like C:/Games/CS:GO/csgo.exe.

I think the latter should be easy to find if I research a little bit more but I cannot find anyway to run the steam games using that link even after hours of research on this matter. I know some other apps like Rainmeter can do it. They can open steam games using just the steam rungame link.

I've tried using:

```
var myScript = Ti.Process.createProcess({
           args:["start", "steam://rungameid/730"]
   });

//Launches the process  
myScript.launch();
```

and just a good old `<a href="steam://rungameid/730"></a>`

But neither of them worked. Can you guys please suggest me something?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone else want to do the same thing then you need to use: `Ti.Platform.openApplication("steam://run/730");`

to run a steam game and something like:

```
Ti.Platform.openApplication("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\Steam.exe");
```

if you want to run an application using a path.